# I can not include page to wordpress function add_filter, the_content

Tags: filters, templates

**Wordpress Function add_filter** 
I want to include extra page, on add_filter How can I correct this ?

 Thanks in Advance !

```
function page_content($content) {
    global $post; 
     if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->ID == 134 ) {

    if(is_page()) {

        $extra_content = ' This is my extra content';
        $content .= $extra_content; 
        $content .= include('horo-header.php'); 
    }
    return $content; 
    }

}

add_filter('the_content', 'page_content');
```

Comment: Why do you want to add new page like that, do you mind posting some additional details about what you want to achieve in here?

Comment: I am creating dynamic content of custom plugin. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the PHP `include()` function will output instead of return data. What you can do is output buffer the include which would look something like:

```
// Start buffering any output
ob_start();

    // Output the include into the buffer.
    include( 'horo-header.php' );

// Append the buffered output into the $content variable
$content .= ob_get_clean();
```

Additionally, you may want to look into `get_template_part()` instead of include. For more information regarding output buffering please review the PHP docs:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for support... Now It's working...

Comment: @AbhijeetShinde Fantastic! If you've found this answer helpful please upvote to show other readers that this is a possible solution. If it ended up solving your problem completely you can click the checkmark to show future readers that this answer solved your problem.

Comment: Howdy_McGee ! Thank you, I have voted, Can you try to answer one more question about redirecting page issue - Here is a question - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/343603/problem-to-redirect-custom-page-using-htaccess-in-wordpress