# Problem to redirect custom page using htaccess

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I could not create dynamic post through URL by `.htaccess`, Page or Post redirect automatically 404 page.

I have tried [Redirection Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/), but i could not successfully redirect. Please try to give me solution, Thanks in advance.

Original Url - `https://example.com/subject-detalis?type=daily&sign=topic`

Modify Url - `https://example.com/subject/daily/topic`

`.htaccess` code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule  ^subject/(\d+)?$ ./subject-detalis?sign=$1&type=$2
```

Comment: If `subject-details` is a WordPress page/post/category/etc., you should use [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) instead of the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: I am not using pages or post category in this project. This is totally dynamic pages.

Comment: So the `subject-details` is a file or folder, which is not handled by WordPress?

Comment: example.com/subject-details - This is a page, which i have create, and i want sent some extra values through Url, like - example.com/subject/daily/topic - which is not handled by WordPress

Comment: I'm saying, is that `example.com/subject-details` a WordPress Page (post type of `page`)? If so, use `add_rewrite_rule()`. In WordPress, you'd only want to use the `RewriteRule` if you're rewriting to a file other than the WordPress' main `index.php` file. Otherwise in your case, WordPress will try to load a Page with the slug `subject/daily/topic` and if not found, results in the 404 error.

Comment: I have tried this code for rewrite_rule, but i coud not redirect 

<p> domain.com/foo/my_page </p><p>
 domain.com/my_page?param=foo </p>
 
function wpd_foo_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^foo/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&param=foo',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_foo_rewrite_rule' ); </pre>

Comment: Well, maybe it's easier for you to just use the Redirection plugin - create a new redirection with the following settings: 1) Source URL: `/subject/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?` 2) Make sure URL Options is set to Regex. 3) Target URL: `/subject-details?type=$1&sign=$2` 4) Click the "settings" icon next to the "Add Redirect" button and make sure the "When matched" is set to `Pass-through`. 5) Click the "Add Redirect" button and test that redirection - go to `example.com/subject/daily/topic`. To access the URL parameters, you can use `$_GET['type']` and `$_GET['sign']`.

Comment: Thank You, So much ! @SallyCJ , It's working !